# linking external JS files in another folder in HTML

Tags: javascript, html

I am trying to link a javascript file to my html but its in another folder here's my HTML code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <link rel="icon" href="%PUBLIC_URL%/favicon.ico" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1" />
    <meta name="theme-color" content="#000000" />
    <meta
      name="description"
      content="Web site created using create-react-app"
    />
    <link rel="apple-touch-icon" href="%PUBLIC_URL%/logo192.png" />

    <link rel="manifest" href="%PUBLIC_URL%/manifest.json" />

    <title>PreFab Davao</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <script src="../src/pages/testing.js"></script>
    <h1>testing</h1>
    <noscript>You need to enable JavaScript to run this app.</noscript>
    <div id="root"></div>
  </body>
</html>
```

the problem is it throws an error:

```
Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token '<' (at testing.js:1:1)
```

the contents of testing.js is litteraly just `console.log("TEST")`

Comment: That is likely a 404 page with HTML in it. You can see in the network tab where the file is residing according to the browser and then fix it

Comment: Open your browser's debugging tools and look at the requests made on the network tab.  Somewhere will be a request for that file.  Does the URL match what you expect?  What is the server's response?

Comment: yeah I checked, its responding with index.html (the current HTML file). Is there someway to fix this

Comment: Yes, fix this `../src/pages/testing.js` if index.html is in pages, then you need `testing.js` etc

Comment: hmm I really dont know what to fix the code with, i do think that `<script src="../src/pages/testing.js"></script>` is the correct way to link javascript files in another folder to an html file, unless it isnt